# Error "The action you have requested is not allowed." when i update form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `Codeigniter` panel for users.
In my site, I have a textarea where my clients put informations and press the "go" button. When the button is pressed, my script get the information of textarea and make a searchers and tests, and return a value.

This working all right in my old site, but now I create a new site in codeigniter, and this not working more. Now, when I press "go" button the page refresh and get this error.

I read about, and I think is an error of CSRF or anything like this.

Someone know whats this error is happends and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code with some explanation on it? As well as the error thrown..

Comment: There can be multiple reason for this. May be controller missing, controller function missing, CSRF not set, action url incorrect. Can you post code so will be easy to understand your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already check CSRF token before and sent to the form ( or maybe an ajax )?

I've experienced that. caused by CSRF which is different from when CSRF is sent and received by form. You can do two things. The first one to take and immediately send the CSRF token manually. The second one uses the GET method (not recommended if you want to POST)